# Array and pointer notation

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm a little confused. Here's the code

```
main(){
    int i=3;
    char p[10]="abcdefdeg";
    char *ptr;
    ptr=p;
    printf("%p\n",&p[i]);     // Gets a normal address
    printf("%p\n",ptr[i]);   // Gets 0x64 
    printf("%p\n",(ptr+i));  // Gets a normal address
}
```

**why ptr[i] and (ptr+i) gets different result**? Aren't these 2 notations supossed to have the same meaning? It seems that when I use array notation with pointer it interprets the contents of the address as the address...but I dont know why

Comment: You want `*(ptr+i)` if you want to access element in the array

Comment: @MightyPork No I dont want the contents, I want the address. I just dont know why I cant do it with ptr[i] too.

Comment: because `ptr[i]` is really just a sugar for `*(ptr + i)`

Answer (score 1):

In this case, `ptr[i]` and `(ptr+i)` are supposed to print different values, and they do. They are not the same.

Actually, `ptr[i]` is equivalent to writing `*(ptr+i)`.

To clarify, `ptr` holds an address and `(ptr+i)` just gives you another  address, incremented by `i`. To get the *value* at the address, (which is done by `ptr[i]`), you need to use the dereference operator `*`.

Also, as mentioned in the comment, the second `printf()` should be `printf("%c\n",ptr[i]);`, as it points to a `char` type.

Comment: Can you tell me why they are not the same?

Comment: They aren't supposed to print different values. If the UB in the second print-statement (due to mismatched printf-format-specifier) happens to be benign, they are just extremely likely to.

Comment: I mean doesnt ptr[i] just means get the contents of ptr add i to it and get that address

Comment: @simple16 nearly, it's "get the contents of (the object) ptr (known as value), add i to it, and get (the object at) that address (known as dereferencing).

Answer (score 0):

```
&p[i] // address of i-th element of array p
p[i] // i-th element of array p
(p+i) // p + i, -> address of i-th element of array p
*(p+i) // i-th element of array p
```

The `[]` notation is really just a syntactic sugar.